REDCAP Date Text Box validation: how I could add a dynamic minimum/maximum based in another date variable
I'am a REDCap 14.0.16 user since a couple of weeks. I'm planning a study for persons between a range of age (for instance between 30 and 60 years).
To prevent the accidental inclusion of participants out of the range of age, I use two variables: the date of assessment [doa] and then the date of birth [dob]. The idea is to subtract 30 and 60 years to the date of assessment to set the maximum and minimum allowed dates for birth respectively.
Both dates are validated in Date (D-M-Y) format, so the result of the validation expression must return a date value, otherwise appears the alert "The value you provided could not be validated because it does not follow the expected format. Required format: Date (D-M-Y)".
Is there any way to prevent the introduction of participants out of the age range?, if so, what I should do?
I've tried using special functions in the minimum and maximum fields, but retrieved the "Required format" error (as is the same problem, I only include the minimum).
Datediff returns a time difference and thus doesn't work.
I've tried with "Functions to use with Dates or DateTime values", namely day, month and year, trying to subtract the age in years to the date of assesment.

minimum: day([doa)-month([doa])-(year([doa])-60) -> Required format error
minimum: day([doa)month([doa])(year([doa])-60)   -> Required format error

As all the above failed, I gave a try to Action Tags in the validation field, although I didn't expect to work because they're misplaced.

minimum: @CALCDATE([doa],-60,'y')   -> Required format error

As it didn't work, I tried to concatenate the expressions, as I expected that the behaviour should be the same than typing manually the dates.

I changed [doa] validation to Date (Y-M-D) following the indications of the help section.
I concatenated the expressions:


minimum: concat((year([doa])-60),month([doa]),day([doa]))-> Required format error
minimum: concat_ws("-",(year([doa])-60),month([doa]),day([doa]))-> Required format error


Two possible work-around solutions here:

Create a data quality rule that executes in real-time on data entry forms, such as [dob]!='' AND (datediff([dob], '[doa]', 'y') < 30 OR datediff([dob], '[doa]', 'y') > 60). This will automatically create a warning whenever the user tries to enroll someone younger than 30 OR older than 60. Also includes a check to make sure the date of birth field is not empty. However, data quality rules can still be manually overridden by the user's choice, which may be useful if there's ever a planned protocol deviation.
The minimum and maximum validation ranges accept piped variables to set dynamic range limits. So you could create separate variables (optionally hiding them from the user using the @HIDDEN action tag) that store these minimum and maximum ranges. So for instance, min_dob would be a stand-alone text field designed to store the value of a @CALCDATE action tag. Then, you could just set the minimum validation range to [min_dob]. And then repeat the same process for your maximum validation range, e.g., create a [max_dob] variable.

